# Sorting result in descending order

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I want my results to be sorted by `a.right` (It might have 2 values: 1 - true, 0 - false). The row where `a.right=1` must come first. Tried `GROUP BY`. But didn't help. How to achieve result above?

```
SELECT
    u.fullname,
    a.id,
    a.content,
    a.addDT,
    a.`right`,
    acr.score,
    acr.checkDT
FROM
    answers a
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = a.uid
LEFT JOIN `answer_chk_results` acr ON acr.aid = a.id
WHERE
    a.qid = 1
GROUP BY
    a.`right` DESC
```

Comment: Have you tried using `ORDER BY` instead of `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 2):

A little mistake. Try `ORDER BY` instead of `GROUP BY`. [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) is used for sorting records while [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) is used for aggregating records.

Your query should be

```
SELECT
    u.fullname,
    a.id,
    a.content,
    a.addDT,
    a.`right`,
    acr.score,
    acr.checkDT
FROM
    answers a
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = a.uid
LEFT JOIN `answer_chk_results` acr ON acr.aid = a.id
WHERE
    a.qid = 1
ORDER BY
    a.`right` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ORDER BY` for sorting results. `GROUP BY` is for aggregating the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending this to the end:

```
ORDER BY
    a.right DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

For sorting you should use ORDER BY:

```
    SELECT
        u.fullname,
        a.id,
        a.content,
        a.addDT,
        a.`right`,
        acr.score,
        acr.checkDT
    FROM
        answers a
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = a.uid
    LEFT JOIN `answer_chk_results` acr ON acr.aid = a.id
    WHERE
        a.qid = 1
    ORDER BY
        a.`right` DESC
```